# Verification of map scale

Tags: scale, wmts, cell-size

A map provider says on its webpage that the ground resolution (respectively pixelsize) is 0.2m x 0.2m.

The WMTS-Capabilities document states on the highest zoom level (`ows:Identifier 16`) a scale denominator of `267`.When considering the standard pixel size of 0.28mm we have everything to calculate the map scale [through](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=35326):

```
pixelSpan = scaleDenominator × 0.28 10-3 / metersPerUnit(crs);
where:
metersPerUnit(Webmercator) => 1 
pixelSize => 0.07
```

The calculated ground resolution of 0.07m is slightly off the 0.2m.
The unit of Web Mercator is [one meter](https://epsg.io/3857) which leads to one meter per unit, right?
But where did I get wrong?

When loading the map in QGIS and zooming in to the maximum and then measured the pixel size I also arrived at 0.07 meters.

Comment: Have you tried loading the WMTS into a GIS, zoomed completely in and then measured the resolution/pixelsize?

Comment: Ah no, good point. I ll try that with QGis

Comment: Just because the server will serve data with that resolution it doesn't mean that the data itself is that resolution, i.e. there can be many screen pixels to the image pixel.

Comment: Calculating scale based on Web Mercator is an exercise in futility, since distances off the Equator can't be accurate (and approach infinitely inaccurate at the poles).

Comment: @Erik yes i tried and the result match the calculated value

Comment: @IanTurton the pixel size matches now the calculated size of 0.07m. This does relate to the image pixels and therefore the data - and should be independent from the device used for displaying the data. So i do not understand where this difference comes from

Comment: @Vince this map convers a world region far away from the poles or the equator. In this case quite usefull

Comment: Another thing to check is if your screen pixels are really .28x10-3 metres across

Comment: "Far away from the equator" is the issue. Every row in Web Mercator has a *different* pixel size, each one getting larger away from the Equator (when the globe actually gets smaller).